# Which Months Fall Between Any Two Dates?

Tags: date, asp-classic

I get show months only on date interval, not days.

```
For i=initDate to endDate
   response.write month(i)
next
```

in this case the result is: `5555555666666667777777......`

Is repeat months for each day in interval, but i get display result only months.

For example: `5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood but maybe this will help. It stores the last month displayed in a variable (lastMonth) and only displays the month if it has changed. It shows the first month because lastMonth is set to zero when created and there should never be a month in the loop of zero.

```vb
Dim lastMonth
lastMonth = 0
For i=initDate to endDate
   If lastMonth <> Month(i) Then
      response.write month(i)
      lastMonth = Month(i)
   End If
next
```

Answer (score 1):

Think [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/858905/john) is on the right track with [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23861711/692942).

But couldn't you simplify the approach by getting the start and end month from your `initDate` and `endDate` variables and stepping through the months?

Something like;

```vb
Dim initMonth, endMonth

initMonth = Month(initDate)
endMonth = Month(endDate)

For i = initMonth To endMonth
  Response.Write i
Next
```

If you are confident that the `initDate` and `endDate` are always Date values you could simplify it further.

```vb
For i = Month(initDate) To Month(endDate)
  Response.Write i
Next
```

Comment: Yes, much shorter and more efficient than my answer, shame on me.